# How to set inital value of text input in Golang?

Tags: go, text, input, stdin, gofmt

I know that you can call for text input from the user in go by doing the following:

```
fmt.Print("Enter text: ")
reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
text, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
```

Which would ouput:

```
Enter text:
```

But is there a way to set an initial value for this input that the user could edit. For example, if the inital value was set to "english", then the output would be:

```
Enter text: english
```

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation would be to put the default value in the prompt:

```
def := "english"
fmt.Printf("Enter text (%s): ", def)
reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
text, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
text = strings.TrimSuffix(text, "\n")
if text == "" {
    text = def
}
```

Comment: This does not set the initial value of the input text. My goal is to make it so when ran, it is as if the word "english" had already been typed in

Comment: I know of no way to do that so I wanted to share the way that I've seen other command line applications handle the default value scenario.

Comment: This is a rather clever and usable workaround, even though it does not answer the question.